# external site using my css and image files, can I block this

Tags: .htaccess, web

each month many gigabytes of traffic on my site is being consumed by various sites, mostly in italy according to my stats.  On further review of my raw access logs, they have built in direct reference links to css and png files in my site.  I can just rename them but that wont stop them accessing a page in my site to get their full urls and keep accessing them.

Is there a way to block access to css and image files in my site unless they come from the same domain, somehow?

Regards

Greg J

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`) (edit the name of the domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule (?:jpg|png|gof|css) - [F]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: that certainly stops it but also stops some other pages in my site, ill check it out further, they must have full web references to the images and css files